# How to get the base64 data URI from a File in Java

Tags: java, base64

I have a `File` object in Java, and I want to get the base64 URI of the file. I am able to get the base64 itself like so:

```
  Base64.encodeBase64(FileUtils.readFileToByteArray(file))
```

However, this is not a URI; does anybody know how I would get that instead? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Assuming I understand your question, you would call [`File.toURI()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/File.html#toURI--) like

```
Base64.encodeBase64(file.toURI())
```